# JQuery trigger function if element is in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I'm trying to make a function `openAnimation()` working, when the element is "in viewport"!

Now, this particular function is GSAP. Every time I run `openAnimation()` doesn't work as aspected. 
Runs twice and repeats each time the `in-view` class is been added.

-So how can I run my GSAP function with this plug in?

https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/qPLoKP

```
function inView( opt ) {
    if( opt.selector === undefined ) {
        console.log( 'Valid selector required for inView' );
        return false;
    }
    var elems = [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( opt.selector ) ),
        once = opt.once === undefined ? true : opt.once,
        offsetTop = opt.offsetTop === undefined ? 0 : opt.offsetTop,
        offsetBot = opt.offsetBot === undefined ? 0 : opt.offsetBot,
        count = elems.length,
        winHeight = 0,
        ticking = false;


    function update() {
        var i = count;
        while( i-- ) {
            var elem = elems[ i ],
                rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
            if( rect.bottom >= offsetTop && rect.top <= winHeight - offsetBot ) {
                elem.classList.add( 'in-view' );

                if( once ) {
                    count--;
                    elems.splice( i, 1 );
                }
            } else {
                elem.classList.remove( 'in-view' );
            }
        }
        ticking = false;

    }

    function onResize() {
        winHeight = window.innerHeight;
        requestTick(); 
    }

    function onScroll() {
        requestTick(); 
    }

    function requestTick() {
        if( !ticking ) {
            requestAnimationFrame( update );
            ticking = true;
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onResize, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'scroll', onScroll, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onScroll, false );

    onResize();
}

inView({
    selector: '.view-poll', // an .in-view class will get toggled on these elements
    once: true, // set this to false to have the .in-view class be toggled on AND off
    offsetTop: 0, // top threshold to be considered "in view"
    offsetBot: 0 // bottom threshold to be considered "in view"
});


// HOW CAN I RUN THIS FUNCTION NOW?

function openAnimation() {

  var rotate = $('.rotate.in-view');
  var scale = $('.scale.in-view');
  var translate = $('.translate.in-view');

  //feature Left

  TweenLite.from(rotate, 1.2, {y:-400, opacity: 0.0, delay:0.0, }, 0.05);
  TweenLite.from(scale, 1.2, {y:-400, opacity: 0.0, delay:0.0, }, 0.05);
  TweenLite.from(translate, 1.2, {y:-400, opacity: 0.0, delay:0.0, }, 0.05);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [jQuery-visible](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible). With its help, you can create a window event `onScroll` and check if your element is "visible", then call your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://scrollmagic.io/. With this you can initiate any function on scroll or when its in view.

Comment: I'll have a look, did you use it before?

Comment: Yes, i have used it before and its quite easy to implement. As you are using the Tweenmax js, you can also figure it out easily.

Comment: In not what I want and what I need though. I'd like to get my question solved first as its a good code and I just need to make it working